# JavaScript - Sort array elments in JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

How can I sort the below JSON string using JavaScript.

Input:

```
[{time:'1 hours ago'}, {time:'10 minutes ago'}, {time:'2 minutes ago'}]
```

Output:

```
[{time:'2 minutes ago'}, {time: '10 minutes ago'}, {time:'1 hours ago'}]
```

Comment: You will have a tough time sorting time when it's representing in `String` format. Is there any reason as to why it's not in unix timestamp format? Sorting with `Number` type is a lot easier because you want it from recent to oldest.

Comment: Parsing strings like '2 minutes ago' will result into and invalid date in JS. You might want to consider changing your input values to some valid timestamp format. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: using JS you need to convert language in numbers, i.e for example: minutes-> 2, 10 ,60 (here 1 hour is converted in minute, with condition if hour number * 60, and so on..) that will make sorting task easy with uniform data

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough sample.

```
var getVal = function(timeStr){
    var arr = timeStr.split(" ");
    var factor = 1;
    switch(arr[1]){
        case "minutes":factor = 1;   break;
        case "hours"  :factor = 60;  break;
        case "days"   :factor = 1440;break;
    }
    return parseInt(arr[0]) * factor;
}

var tgt = [{time:'2 minutes ago'}, {time: '10 minutes ago'}, {time:'1 hours ago'}];

tgt.sort(function(a,b){
    return getVal(a.time) - getVal(b.time);
});

console.log(tgt);
```